# cloudstack secondary stoarge vm

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I am using apache cloudstack. System VMs are in running state but unable to download system template. when I am login to system VMs through ssh using linked local ip then the it is not able to ping DNS,Management server and host.

Answer (score 0):

check it has the correct management server ip and all routes are proper.
You could try a destroy to recreate the SSVM.